# Ext.form.Panel, Ext 5, Align Labels and Fields

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am utilizing an [Ext.form.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel), it's configurations are as follows:

```
defaultType : 'textfield',
layout      : 'auto',
height      : '60%',
width       : '40%',
floating    : true,
modal       : true,
renderTo    : Ext.getBody(),
closeAction : 'destroy', // default; invoked via the .close() method
```

Within this form, I have a number of `textfield` type components, each with a corresponding label. The configuration, beyond their label and name, is identical and is as follows:

```
 fieldLabel : 'Dimension Label',
 name       : 'dimensionLabel',
 labelWidth : '400px', // to exagerate the label size
 padding    : '10px'
```

I would like to align the input fields, not necessarily the label (as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743012/align-group-of-labels-and-inputs) regarding the .Net Framework); however, my input fields are aligning, as follows:

[image: The fields, themselves, are not aligned]

A number of SO posts suggest the `labelAlign` configuration for the `FormPanel`; however, it is not an available configuration for the `Ext.form.Panel` in Ext JS 5 (I don't know when it was previously available). If I attempt to configure it, the configuration is ignored. I have tried both on the field and panel level.

Is it possible to align the above fields on the left? Someone else on the Sencha forums suggest utilizing a `fieldset`; however, this also does not have the above mentioned configuration.

Comment: Like this? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ls5

Comment: @CD.. perfect! That's what I am looking for. If you are able to expand it into an answer (?), I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`form`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Form) layout:

> This is a layout that will render form Fields, one under the other all stretched to the Container width.

See working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ls5

---

Alternatively you can use the [`anchor`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Anchor) layout:

> This is a layout that enables anchoring of contained elements relative to the container's dimensions.

See working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ls7